# Qt. Как сохранить настройки языка в QSettings?

Tags: c++, qt

Например, пользователь выбрал русский язык для интерфейса приложения и при последующих запусках интерфейс загружался на русском.

Comment: в чем именно вопрос? сохраняйте строку языка в настройки, при загрузке анализируйте, какой язык выбран и грузите нужный файл перевода

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313896/changing-locale-in-qt

*Выбрали язык в UI и ассоциировали его с кодом локали, например русский*

```
QString locale_code = "ru_RU";
...
QLocale locale(locale_code);
QLocale::setDefault( locale ); // !< Будет грузится по умолчанию
```

Все. Настройки тут не нужны. Совсем.